# Is there a way to use and_then with different error types without map_err?

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have some functions that will return a different error type when failing.

First I have a builder, which contains this method:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum BuilderError {
    ElementMissing(&'static str),
}

pub fn spawn(self) -> Result<ServiceStatus, BuilderError>
```

So it will return a `BuildError` on failure.

Now, I have another function that will return another error:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum XmlError {
    XmlCreationFailed(writer::Error),
    ConversionToUtf8(FromUtf8Error),
}

pub fn create_xml(service_status: super::ServiceStatus) -> Result<String, XmlError>
```

The idea is that I use the builder to create a `ServiceStatus` object and use it to create a XML string with `create_xml` function.

To do that, I have this code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum WebserviceError {
    XmlError(XmlError),
    BuilderError(BuilderError),
}

impl std::error::Error for WebserviceError {
    ...
}

impl From<XmlError> for WebserviceError {
    fn from(error: XmlError) -> WebserviceError {
        WebserviceError::XmlError(error)
    }
}

impl From<BuilderError> for WebserviceError {
    fn from(error: BuilderError) -> WebserviceError {
        WebserviceError::BuilderError(error)
    }
}

fn test() -> Result<String, status::WebserviceError> {
    ...
    let service_status = builder.spawn()?;
    let xml = status::create_xml(service_status)?;
    Ok(xml)
}
```

Now, I think I can do better using `and_then` instead of using ? operator:

```
fn test() -> Result<String, status::WebserviceError> {
    ...
    builder
        .spawn()
        .map_err(status::WebserviceError::BuilderError)
        .and_then(|hue| status::create_xml(hue).map_err(status::WebserviceError::XmlError))
}
```

This solution works too, but now I need to explicitly call `map_err` to convert from a `BuilderError` or `XmlError` to a `WebserviceError`...

So, my question is, can I do better? I think a solution like this would be ideal:

```
fn test() -> Result<String, status::WebserviceError> {
    ...
    builder
        .spawn()
        .and_then(status::create_xml)
}
```

Comment: I think you can do `.map_err(Into::into)` and let rustc figure out which impl applies. But I prefer the solution with `?`

Answer (score 5):

If you're not really interested in exact error, but raise some final error in the end you can use something like:

```
builder.spawn().ok()
    .and_then(|v| status.create_xml(v).ok())
    .ok_or_else(|| SomeError('failed to create xml'))
```

Answer (score 4):

After some trial, here is the solution:

```
trait CustomAndThen<T, E> {
    fn and_then2<U, E2, F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E2>>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
        where E: std::convert::From<E2>;
}

impl<T, E> CustomAndThen<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn and_then2<U, E2, F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E2>>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
        where E: std::convert::From<E2>
    {
        match self {
            Ok(t) => op(t).map_err(From::from),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }
}

...

Ok(builder)
    .and_then2(status::ServiceStatusBuilder::spawn)
    .and_then2(status::create_xml)
```

This will create a custom `and_then` function for `Result` type that will make the conversion inside it, clearing the code